# Silverlight MVVM - Modal dialog binding save or rollback

Tags: silverlight, modal-dialog, mvvm-light

I have a Silverlight MVVM (light toolkit) application with a modal dialog (ChildWindow).

What is the best way to bind data to the modal dialog, and by OK save that or by Cancel make a rollback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm), which addresses the same issue. Seems to be very helpful and I have used it myself in the past.

Comment: Not the same, but thanks, it helped! Here is a [link](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/209338?ProjectName=mvvmlight) to a useful discussion