# Load UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, ribbon-control

I have a `RibbonControl` in a small WPF application, and I have a button called Search.  My idea is that when I press this button in the Main Window, I load a user control, and I wish to get a result like "TweetDeck" does, ie every time I press the Search button, the user control is pinned in the main window.

Is there a tutorial or an example of how I can do this?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the user control is pinned in the main window". That sounds like a modal dialog, check this :
[Handling Dialogs in WPF with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)

Comment: I was thinking more on a simple approach, since I have not gone into MVVM yet.  At the moment I have something hardcoded which works                 <local:UC1 Width="300" Height="700" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></local:UC1>

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed to solve my problem

```
    UserControl uc1 = new UCTeamTweet();
    uc1.Width = Convert.ToInt32("300");
    uc1.Height = Convert.ToInt32("700");
    uc1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    uc1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    stkPnlSearch.Children.Add(uc1);
```

I do not know if its the right solution though it works fine for my purposes