# How to open child window in mainwindow in MMVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 3 screens

Mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PatientAdminTool.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel></vm:MainViewModel>    
    </Window.DataContext>
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome 
        CaptionHeight="0"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <ContentControl >
        <v:PatientWindow DataContext="{Binding PatientVM}"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Window>
```

PatientWindow.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PatientAdminTool.View.PatientWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.ViewModel"
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:PatientSelectorVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True" Height="40" Background="#646161" >
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin=" 10,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Patients" FontSize="16"  TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10,10,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Transparent"  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" >
                    <StackPanel Background="Transparent"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button Focusable="False" ToolTip="Close" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#646161" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Padding="-4" Command="{Binding CloseCommand,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Grid Width="45" Height="23">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White"   Text="r" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button.Content>
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <v:PatientSelector DataContext="{Binding PatientSelectorVM}" />
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image] Result should be as per the below image

I need to show the child window by using corresponding view model.
I am not getting how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access UI elements (including windows) in ViewModels directly.

Just make abstraction of the functionality "Open Window". The easiest way is to use interface:

```
interface IDialogService 
{
    public void OpenWindow(BaseViewModel windowViewModel);
}

//in viewmodel:
void OpenPatientWindow_CommandExecuted()
{
     var patientWindowVM = new PatientWindowViewModel())
     patientWindowVM.Parameter = "This way you can pass parameters";
    _dialogService.OpenWindow(patientWindowVM);
}
```

go here for more inspiration: [Handling Dialogs in WPF with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Content property of ContentPresenter to the *PatientVM* property of the `MainViewModel` in MainWindow.xaml and use define a DataTemplate per child view/view model type:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PatientVM}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:PatientSelectorVM">
            <v:PatientWindow />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ThirdScreenType">
            <v:ThirdScreenView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

You then set the `PatientVM` property of the `MainViewModel` to a `PatientSelectorVM` object to display the PatientWindow view and to a `ThirdScreenType` object (or whatever your class is actually called) to display the other view in the ContentControl.

Make sure that the `MainViewModel` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `PatientVM` property:

```
public BaseViewModel PatientVM
{
    get { return _patientVM; }
    set
    {
        patientVM = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

For you to be able to set the property to both a PatientSelectorVM object and the other type of objects, these classes should derive from the same base class or implement the same interface.