# How to load usercontrol in Mainwindow in MVVM WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `MainWindow.Xaml` file. And one usercontrol `PatientWindow.Xaml`. How to load the patient window in mainwindow in MVVM architecture?

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PatientAdminTool.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.ViewModel"
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.View"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" 
        WindowStyle="None"  
        WindowState="Normal"  
        Title="PatientAdmin Tools"           
        Height="750"
        Width="1400"
        AllowsTransparency="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown" BorderThickness="1"  BorderBrush="#555252"  >  
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome 
        CaptionHeight="0"     
          />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
</Window>
```

PatientWindow.xaml

Usercontrol window is mentioned in below

```
<UserControl x:Class="PatientAdminTool.View.PatientWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.ViewModel"
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True" Height="40" Background="#646161" >
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin=" 10,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Patients" FontSize="16"  TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="10,10,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Transparent"  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" >
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button Focusable="False" ToolTip="Close" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#646161" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Padding="-4" Click="Button_Click" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Grid Width="45" Height="23">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="White"   Text="r" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button.Content>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>

                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So I need to load the patient window above of main window using MVVM. Here I need to write load event in corresponding View Model. Please help me to do this.

Comment: You want to display the UserControl in the Window?

Comment: Yes.when am running the project , I need to see meainwindow above that my usercontrol need to be display.

Comment: In the same window, or a new window?

Comment: Yes same window

Comment: if you are using MVVM then you should probably be using templates not usercontrols, user controls are only required when you need a code behind file

Comment: @MikeT I disagree. For a start almost all the MVVM frameworks I've seen use UserControls. Having a code-behind file has very little overhead, even if you don't use it.

Comment: Are you asking anything different from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633217/how-to-open-child-window-in-mainwindow-in-mmvm-wpf. I notice you didn't accept any answers from that, or even make any comment on any answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `ControlPresenter` at MainWindow.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding YouTypeHere}">
             <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fristViewModel1Type}">
                     <youControlForViewModel1 />
                 </DataTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type secondViewModel2Type}">
                     <youControlForViewModel2 />
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
         </ContentPresenter>
```

And you could change Views via binding different VM to ContentPresenter.

Comment: what I need to mention binding property "youtypehere" and "<youControlForViewModel2 />".

Comment: @Shri yep just some pseudo-cod, forget to describe :(,  'youtypehere' is property on main viewmodel and must be of type 'firstViewModelType' or 'secondViewModelType'.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to open a new **child window** using MVVM? I assume you would open it from MainWindowViewModel.

#### Solution 1: without strict MVVM

Sometimes its fine to **open it directly** from the ViewModel:

```
private void OnOpenPatientWindowCommandExecute()
{
    var o = new PatientWindow();
    o.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

For this you would have to change **PatientWindow** from **UserControl** to a **Window**.

#### Solution 2: strict MVVM

The solutions **following strict MVVM** are a little more complex. In the solution I write here you would have to use a **Service**, add it to your **MainWindowViewModel** and bind a control from the view to a **Command** in the ViewModel. Also, its written as if you are using *Dependency Injection*, that's why you see the service injected in the constructor. You can avoid this by just instantiating the service in the constructor.

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using Prism.Wpf.Commands; // For easy commands
using PatientAdminTool.Services; // Where you put your new service

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
   private IShowDialogService _ShowDialogService;

   public MainWindowViewModel(IShowDialogService showDialogService)
   {
       _ShowDialogService = showDialogService;

       // Or do: _ShowDialogService = new ShowDialogService();
       // But that's not a good practice and won't let you test
       // this ViewModel properly.

       OpenPatientWindowCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnOpenPatientWindowCommandExecute);
   }

   public ICommand OpenPatientWindowCommand { get; private set; }

   private void OnOpenPatientWindowCommandExecute()
   {
       _ShowDialogService.ShowPatientWindow();
   }
}
```

Services\IShowDialogService.cs

```
public interface IShowDialogService
{
    void ShowPatientWindow();

    void ShowOtherWindow();

    // ...
}
```

Services\ShowDialogService.cs

```
public class ShowDialogService : IShowDialogService
{
    public void ShowPatientWindow()
    {
        var patientWindowViewModel = new PatientWindowViewModel();
        var patientWindow = new PatientWindow();

        patientWindow.DataContext = patientWindowViewModel;

        patientWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void ShowOtherWindow()
    {
        // Other window ...
    }
}
```

Finally, you make the connection in the View like this:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.ViewModel">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding OpenPatientCommand}">Open Patient</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Haven't tried it in Visual Studio yet but that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the only thing you are going to be displaying **in the same** window, just put your view in there like any other control:

```
<Window x:Class="PatientAdminTool.MainWindow"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:PatientAdminTool.View"... >  
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome 
        CaptionHeight="0"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <v:PatientWindow/>
</Window>
```

Do you have a root ViewModel for your window? If so, you can bind to a PatientViewModel:

```
<v:PatientWindow DataContext="{Binding PatientViewModel}"/>
```

If not, it's common to set the first DataContext to a ViewModel in the code-behind like this:

```
<v:PatientWindow Name="PatientWindowView"/>
```

and:

```
public partial class Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PatientWindowView.DataContext = new PatientWindowViewModel();

    }
}
```

If you want to display more than one View, use a ContentPresenter like Shakra has answered.

If you want to open a new window, use what Alberto Cardona López has suggested.

Comment: Good answer but you have missed a few bits like, templating and adding the namespace

Comment: What do you mean by Templating? Something like @Shakra's answer? If so, I mentioned that in the answer. Not sure you need to Template if you just have a single view, seemed that was more complex than the asker wanted. I didn't say how to add the namespace as the question contains it - but I've added it in case someone else stumbles on this and gets confused.